# Refresh/Call PrototypeJs Event from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I have a Magento Website. I have two js files, one written in Prototype an one in jQuery.

I have two select elements, with about 10 options. From jQuery I'm changing the first select's attribute "selected" (an some more). In Prototype I have a class that creates dependencies between two select elements.

If I click on the first select element and choose an option with the mouse, on the second select element will appear only the options that are linked to the option I choosed in the first select element. This is allready done in prototype.

The idea is that I want to do the click/trigger automatically from jQuery. The first select change it's selected option. But the second select element display all the options (and should display only the options linked to the first select element).

On the Prototype file I have some Event Observers, and I guess that these observers are not triggered from jQuery:

```
var select_el = $('select_' + id);
...
Event.observe(select_el, 'change', this.update.bindAsEventListener(this));
Event.observe(select_el, 'swatches:change', this.update.bindAsEventListener(this));
...
update: function(event) { ...
```

So I need somehow to trigger these events from jQuery, or to set an autocheck in Prototype.
Please tell me what should I do.

I've read on stackoverflow that events from Prototype can't be triggered from jQuery. There should be a way to do that. I just haven't found it.

I've tried jQuery functions like:

```
  jQuery("option[value='" + checkedId +"']").attr("selected","selected").parent().focus();


  jQuery("option[value='" + checkedId +"']").parent().trigger("onchange");

  jQuery("option[value='" + checkedId +"']").parent().trigger('change');
```

Where the "parent()" is the first select element. The first select element changes as I want, but the second select element should automatically change after the first select is changed. And this never happens. It works only if I click with the mouse on the select and choose manually an option. I want to do this from jQuery, without being necessary to manually click on the desired option.

Thanks for reading this, and now just give me a fix for this problem.

Regards.

Comment: any idea regarding the fix of this problem?

Comment: Any reason you don't add the observers in both libraries? It looks like you have a separate function to handle the events, and not using a closure, so you can define both observers to use the same handler. Just an idea.

Comment: I handle events in PrototypeJs, I automatically change the select from Jquery. The Event observer can't see jQuery's change. How can I solve this?